# Using rails form_for to retrieve records not create them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have  bike model:

```
class Bike < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :make
    has_one :model
    has_one :year
```

I am trying to implement a form on my app's home page that has three `collection_select` inputs (the second two are dynamically populated based on the prior collection_select's selected value using AJAX) for make, model, and year.  The form itself renders and all AJAX requests are working.

Upon submit, I would like to render the existing Bike model record's show page that matches the user's selection (based on the id's of the selected values in the collection_selects).

Here is the form (this is on the homepage and not the Bike's new page). I have created a search action in the bike controller but do not know how to pass any data to it:

```
<%= form_for(:bike, :url => {:controller => 'bikes', :action => 'search'}, :html => {:role => "form", :class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= label :make_id, 'Make' %>
            <%= collection_select(:bike, :make_id, Make.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, {:class=>'form-control'})%>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="bikeModels"
                <p><%= render 'shared/model_questions_fields', :current_models => [] %></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="modelYears"
                <p><%= render 'shared/year_questions_fields', :current_years => [] %></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit "Show Quote", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
    <% end %>
```

shared/model_questions_fields

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
// when the #model field changes
  $("#bike_model_id").change(function() {
    // make a POST call and replace the content
    var model = $('select#bike_model_id :selected').val();
    if(model == "") model="0";
    jQuery.get('/bikes/update_year_select/' + model, function(data){
        $("#modelYears").html(data);
    })
    return false;
  });
})
</script>

<%= label :model_id, 'Model' %>
<% if !current_models.blank? %>
    <%= collection_select :bike, :model_id, current_models, :id , :name, {include_blank: true}, {:class=>'form-control'} %>
<% else %>
    <%= collection_select :bike, :model_id, [], :id , :name, {include_blank: true}, {:class=>'form-control'} %>
<% end %>
```

shared/year_questions_fields

```
<%= label :year_id, 'Year' %>
<% if !current_years.blank? %>
    <%= collection_select :bike, :year_id, current_years, :id , :year_value, {include_blank: true}, {:class=>'form-control'} %>
<% else %>
    <%= collection_select :bike, :year_id, [], :id , :year_value, {include_blank: true}, {:class=>'form-control'} %>
<% end %>
```

bikes_controller

```
class BikesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_bike, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /bikes
  # GET /bikes.json
  def index
    @bikes = Bike.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  # GET /bikes/1
  # GET /bikes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /bikes/new
  def new
    @bike = Bike.new
  end

  def search
    @bike = Bike.find_by(:make_id => make_id, :model_id => model_id, :year_id => year_id)
    redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @bike.bike_id
  end

  def update_model_select
    models = Model.where(:make_id=>params[:id]).order(:name) unless params[:id].blank?
    render :partial => "shared/model_questions_fields", :locals => { :current_models => models }
  end

  def update_year_select
    model = Model.find(params[:id])
    render :partial => "shared/year_questions_fields", :locals => { :current_years => model.years }
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_bike
      @bike = Bike.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def bike_params
      params.require(:bike).permit(:year_id, :make, :make_id, :model, :model_id, :kind, 
        :msrp, :current_price, :customer_id, :side_picture, :like_new_value, :excellent_value, :good_value,
        :fair_value)
    end
end
```

I need to get the bike_id based on the make_id, model_id, and year the user selects. I am confused on how to get the record via the controller.

Comment: can you provide the shared files like: year_questions_fields and model_questions_fields?

Comment: added.  I am not sure they are relevant - what I am confused about is the setup of the form_for.

Comment: What version of rails are you running? And can you post your bikes controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most efficient or best way, but I was able to solve this with the following code:

bikes_controller

```
def search
    puts params[:bike][:make_id]
    bike = Bike.find_by(:make_id => params[:bike][:make_id], :model_id => params[:bike][:model_id], :year_id => params[:bike][:year_value])
    redirect_to :action => "show", :id => bike.id
end
```

I was incorrectly accessing the parameters (they were nested).